# Detect when VGA monitor is plugged

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Is there a way to detect when an external monitor is plugged to the VGA port in Ubuntu Linux, using a Python script? Should I poll using xrandr, or [monitor a UDEV message](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122301/9108)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [srandrd](https://github.com/jceb/srandrd). It's a [randr](https://www.x.org/wiki/Projects/XRandR/) daemon for which you can install handlers to be run for certain events, like a monitor connecting, for instance.

If you have the following script in "handler.sh":

```sh
#!/bin/sh
case "$S{RANDRD_OUTPUT} ${SRANDRD_EVENT}" in
  "VGA-0 connected")
  # React to event.
  ;;
esac
```

Then you can install the handler via:

```sh
% srandrd handler.sh
```